# Ember Controllers and "virtual" and/or "abstract" methods?

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, ember.js, controller

I am aware that JS isn't designed to handle inheritance per OOP "cleanly", but I wonder if Ember has a way to pull this off.

In Ember, I figure that `Ember.ObjectController.extend({...});` is somewhat inheritance, but not completely - we surely can add our own properties and methods, hence the function `.extend({...})`, but we can't "override" a function that already exists. I wonder if there is such a workaround to this.

If I created a base controller, how would I define functions that I want child controllers to implement? I have the base controller (theory code only):

```
App.BaseController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
     // Methods meant for a child controller to implement 
     abstractMethod1: null,
     abstractMethod2: null,
     virtualMethod1: function(){
         ...
     },
     actions: {
        execute: function(){
             if(this.get("abstractMethod1"))
                 this.get("abstractMethod1")();
             ...
             if(this.get("abstractMethod2")
                 var x = this.get("abstractMethod2")();
        }
    }
});
```

Then I have an implementing controller trying to override those functions:

```
App.ImplementingController = App.BaseController.extend({
    /* How would I implement abstractMethod1 and abstractMethod2 here!?
       For virtualMethod1, how would I call something like base.virtualMethod1()
       or super.virtualMethod1()?
    */
});
```

I found myself creating a ton of controllers that have basically the same code, except for the name of the model and its properties. It would be nice to be able to pull of this scheme in Ember. What to do?

Answer (score 1):

Actually Ember does that perfectly fine, you just don't override it and it hits the base implementation.  Or you do override it and it blasts away the base implementation.  (this is essentially how Mixins work as well, http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Mixin.html)  And if you want to hit a `base` function, property etc, it's just accessed with this (it essentially smashes the two classes together, giving precedence to the extended class.

#### Base

```
App.BaseController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  a:'Base',
  b:'Base',
  acomp: function(){
    return 'Base';
  }.property(),
  bcomp: function(){
    return 'Base';
  }.property(),
  e:function(){
    return 'Base';
  },
  f:function(){
    return 'Base';
  }
});
```

#### Extended

```
App.IndexController = App.BaseController.extend({
  b:'Index',
  c:'Index',
  bcomp: function(){
    return 'Index';
  }.property(),
  f:function(){
    return 'Index';
  },
  actions:{
    foo:function(){
      console.log(this.e());
      console.log(this.f());
    }
   }
});
```

#### What it looks like after Ember Combines them

```
App.IndexController....
      a:'Base'
      b:'Index',
      c:'Index',
      acomp: function(){
        return 'Base';
      }.property(),
      bcomp: function(){
        return 'Index';
      }.property(),
      e:function(){
        return 'Base';
      },
      f:function(){
        return 'Index';
      },
      actions:{
        foo:function(){
          console.log(this.e());
          console.log(this.f());
        }
       }
    });
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/wuhuleje/2/edit

Comment: This is good to know. Calling this.e() from the derived controller will call the most derived "version" of the function. However, I want to call this.e() from the base controller, hoping that the derived controller's e() function would be called.